# SSRS 2008 R2 - Stop auto generation of report parameters

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, bids

When adding a new Dataset to a report based off a stored procedure that has parameters (say @MileageLow and @MileageHigh) sometimes those stored procedure parameters are propagated into the actual report parameters.
Is there an option like "Auto Generate Report Parameters" that I can uncheck to prevent BIDS from performing this action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to specify the report parameters during the creation of the DataSet itself.
I was in the habit of just creating it and then going in after and setting the parameters.
  SSRS assigns parameters automatically on a best guess basis.

Answer (score 3):

What I do when only having drop boxes is add a `<Please Select>` with value NULL to the drop down via UNION ALL (if based on query).  I then set this to the default, and in the main report dataset add a big fat

```
IF  @MileageLow IS NULL RETURN
```